# simple form - Reddit-like site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I completed a search and found this topic that is close, How do I make simple form to use, I'm too new to fully understand
what I was looking at.

The answer was as follows:

Step 1
    rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap  (which I did after adding the Gem and running Bundle Install)

Step 2
Told me to add wrappers (not sure if I need to complete this step)

Step 3
modify the simple_form and has this example:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@contact, url: supplier_contacts_path, html: { class: 
'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :c_regular,wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
<%= f.input_field :c_regular, :label => "Regular",class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My code is as follows(views/comments/show.html.erb):

```
<div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial => @link.comments %>
</div>

<%= simple_form_for(@link, html {class: 'form-horizontal' })  do |f| %>  
<div class="field">  
  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
</div>  
<%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: 'btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my partial(views/comments/_comments.html.erb):

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
<div class="comments_wrapper clearfix">
<div class="pull-left">
<p class="lead"><%= comment.body %></p>
<p><small>Submitted <strong><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> 
ago</strong> by
<%= comment.user.email %></small></p>
</div>
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<% if comment.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you 
sure?' }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: What is the issue - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: Sorry, took so long to format; totally, forgot to post the query.  How do I get the Comment box to show?  No error...just on Comment box is displaying.

Comment: No, but I'm willing to try.

Comment: When I ran the Simple Form install, it generated the following:  Inside your views, use the 'simple_form_for' with one of the Bootstrap form
  classes, '.form-horizontal' or '.form-inline', as the following:
    = simple_form_for(@user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |form|

Comment: I had the following: <div id="comments">
  
<%= render :partial => @link.comments %>
</div>

<%= simple_form_for (@link, Comment.new) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    
<%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
  
</div>  Someone suggested changing it the <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>

Comment: @Ethan didn't work but thanks for trying.

Comment: So, I did F12 and the simple form code block isn't showing...any clues?